# RAILS 3 - Transactions in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, transactions, controller

I have an example Action in a Controller.

```
def some_action
 product = Product.new
 product.name = "namepro"
  if product.save
   client.update_attribute(:product_id,product.id)
  end
end
```

How to add transactions for this code? I try with this example code:

```
def some_action
 **transaction do**
  product = Product.new
  product.name = "namepro"
   if product.save
    client.update_attribute(:product_create,Time.now)
   end
 **end**
end
```

But it produces this error:

```
undefined method `transaction'
```

I read about using transactions in Controllers is a bad practice but I don't know why is the reason (http://markdaggett.com/blog/2011/12/01/transactions-in-rails/)

In the example, if product has been created and saved and the client update fail... Rails must not do nothing.

thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use a transaction in a controller if you really want to.  As you noted, it's bad practice, but if you want to do it, just call `Product.transaction do` instead of `transaction do`.  `transaction` is a class method on `ActiveRecord::Base`, so you need to call it on an ActiveRecord-derived class.  Any model class in your application will do (nit-picking caveat: if you are connecting to different databases for different models, that may not be true...but you're probably not doing that).

The reason this is a bad practice is that it doesn't properly separate concerns according to the MVC paradigm.  Your controller shouldn't be so concerned with your data persistence implementation.  A better approach would be to add a method to `Product`.  Maybe something like this:

```
def save_and_update_create_time
  transaction do
    if save
      client.update_attribute(:product_create, Time.now)
    end
  end
end
```

Then instead of calling `product.save` in your controller, call `product.save_and_update_client_create_time`.  You may need to pass `client` to that method too; it's unclear from your code where `client` comes from.  If it's an attribute on `product`, then the method above should work.

There are better, more Railsy ways to do this, too, especially if a `product` knows about its `client` without needing any controller data.  Then you can just use an [`after_save`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_save) callback, like this (add to `Product` class):

```
after_save :update_client

private

def update_client(product)
  product.client.update_attribute(:product_create, Time.now)
end
```

Then every time a `Product` is saved, the field on the associated client will be updated.  You'll possibly have to introduce some code to check for the existence of a `client` first.

The benefit to using callbacks, besides cleaner code, is that the entire callback chain runs in a single transaction along with the save; you don't need to create the transaction manually.  You can read more about callbacks in the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot Jim, you really help me with your explanation!

Comment: If transactional logic is put into a Model, would transactions not be restricted to one Model then, to not break separate concerns rule? Usually there is a high chance that transactions span across multiple Models, which are not necessarily related to each other at DB level.

Comment: Yeah, I've had a change of heart on that particular aspect of my comment. I do like the idea of keeping it out of the controller, but multi-model interactions should be wrapped somewhere. Perhaps another class, but in some situations the controller might be the right place after all.

Comment: I think if you need to spawn transactions across multiple models you need aggregate root model. Martin Fowler writes about it here http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html